# Prevent TcpClient's NetworkStream ReadTimeout from closing the socket

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I have a class the communicates with a device over TCP.
I send commands, and then issue `stream.Read(reply, 0, 1)` on the TcpClient's GetStream().
I read out every single byte, and then combine the read bytes in a string, and compare the string to a termination string which lets me know when to stop reading.

There are some flaws in the device software, so that the termination string is not always sent. I would like to handle this in a proper way and using a period of time to determine whether the read should be stopped.

If I set the `stream.ReadTimeout` to something other than `-1`, then the socket will be closed when this timeout is exceeded, which I don't want it to.

If I use the `stream.BeginRead(..)` with a `stream.ReadTimeout = -1` then I will be sucking dry the thread pool after a while.

What intelligent solution can be constructed to address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I managed to implement something using `stream.DataAvailable`.</strike>

It goes like this:

```
do
{
    try
    {
        if (socket.Poll(socketTimeout, SelectMode.SelectRead))
        {
            socket.Receive(reply, 0, 1, SocketFlags.None);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SocketException((int)SocketError.TimedOut);
        }
        replyString.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reply, 0, reply.Length));
        // Termination string logic...
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        // Check on e.SocketErrorCode if necessary.
        break;
    }

} while (!terminationReached);
```

where `socket = _tcpClient.Client;`

**Edit:**
`socket.Receive` also closes the socket on timeout, `socket.Poll` does not.
<strike>Changed to using `socket.Receive(..)` instead of `stream.Read(..)`.</strike>

Comment: This is terrible. You're busy-waiting if no data is available. And you're swallowing all exceptions incl. bugs.

Comment: The data is received slower than the loop completes, i.e. stream.DataAvailable is false even though the sender has not finishing sending. The timeout prevents the loop for being endless. I see no solution to this. Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: Use the Socket class directly to read with timeout and without closing the stream. ; The loop is not endless bot it will burn a full CPU core for 30s or so. That's death for performance.

Comment: Awesome. Implemented the socket.Receive instead. Updated the solution to reflect.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that having a timeout on the socket also closes the stream.

Comment: As the code stands you break out of the loop when a timeout occurs. Is the code in this posting still current?

Comment: Yes. Although in my production code, I set a timeout flag before the break, and I don't actually use the try/catch/throw structure.

Comment: +1000 - This solution works exactly as desired. It allows timeouts without closing the underlying socket connection. Although, I think the example code could use some cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

You could check `stream.DataAvailable()`

If there is data available in the stram: Read it, combine the read bytes in a string, and compare the string to a termination string.

If there is no termination string, set a timeout (You could use a thread) and wait for any incoming data, if there is no new incoming data set the ReadTimeout to 1, else read the new data.

Comment: Problem with setting the `ReadTimeout > -1` is that it closes the stream.

Comment: DataAvailable is not reliable.